# Iterate over keys grouped by same value in hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

i have a problem.
My question is probably stupid but it's late and i'm exhausted. I work with only one hash (one dimension) that contains unique keys (for sure) and one value. But there are keys which has the same value. I would like to iterate over the grouping keys with the same value but i struggle a lot; In fine, i need both value and key. But my code overloops and i have all keys by value whereas i want to have all keys with one specific value.
The key contains string and values are the file which are from.
I would like an output like this :
To simplify, i have now all item (key) by value (filename).
I want all items from one file, other items from another file and no loop again and again. I don't know how to articulate looping through value and within this value, looping on each key with this value. Here is my code  :

```
    sub write_items_file{

        open my $output, ">:encoding(utf-8)", "bao1_regex_file.xml" or die "$!";
        my $global_counter = 1;
        my @values =uniq(values %$items_file);
        foreach my $value(@values){
            print $output "<file = \"$value\">\n";
            my @keys = grep {$items_file->{$_} == $value} keys %$items_file;
            foreach my $key(@keys){
                print("$key\n");
                my @t_d = split /\|\|/, $key;
                # on écrit les données dans le fichier xml de sortie avec le nom du fichier associé pour chaque item
                print $output "<item numero=\"$global_counter\" date=\"$t_d[2]\">\n<titre>$t_d[0]</titre>\n";
                print $output "<description>$t_d[1]</description>\n</item>\n";
                $global_counter++;
            }
            print $output "</file>\n";
        }

        close $output;
    }
```

I would like the following output :

```
<file = "2020/06/01/19-36-00/0,2-3476,1-0,0.xml">
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="2" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="3" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="4" date="20200607">
</file>

<file = "otherfile.xml">

<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
</file>
<file = "an other file.xml">
<item numero="5" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="6" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="7" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
</file>
```

But i have

```
<file = "2020/06/01/19-36-00/0,2-3476,1-0,0.xml">
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="2" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="3" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="4" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="5" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="6" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="7" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="2" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="3" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="4" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="5" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="6" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="7" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="8" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="9" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="10" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="11" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="12" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="13" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
</file>

<file = "other file.xml">

<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="2" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="3" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="4" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="5" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="6" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="7" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="2" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="3" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="4" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="5" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="6" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="7" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
<item numero="1" date="20200601">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="8" date="20200603">
<titre>Joao Nicolau : « Ce qui guide mon travail c’est le plaisir ».</titre>
<description>Dans « Technoboss », le réalisateur portugais Joao Nicolau montre que « le vieillissement n’est pas un mal inexorable ».</description>
</item>
<item numero="9" date="20200618">
<titre>La Cinémathèque française propose trois œuvres de jeunesse de Jean-Claude Brisseau.</titre>
<description>Les amateurs peuvent découvrir trois moyens-métrages inédits du cinéaste, tournés entre 1966 et 1968, sur la plate-forme de l’institution culturelle.</description>
</item>
<item numero="10" date="20200607">
<titre>Jeux, set et films : dix longs-métrages sur le monde du tennis pour attendre Roland-Garros.</titre>
<description>En attendant la réouverture des salles de cinéma, le 22 juin, le service Culture du « Monde » propose chaque semaine une sélection de films à regarder sur les plates-formes ou en replay.</description>
<item numero="11" date="20200602">
<titre>Michel Piccoli à propos de ses réalisateurs : « J’ai souvent été un double ».</titre>
<description>L’acteur à la filmographie prestigieuse, mort le 12 mai 2020 à l’âge de 94 ans, s’est régulièrement confié dans les pages du « Monde » au sujet des réalisateurs qui ont émaillé sa carrière. Extraits.</description>
</item>
<item numero="12" date="20200605">
<titre>A défaut de palmarès, Cannes décerne son label à 56 films.</titre>
<description>Privés de Festival en raison de l’épidémie due au Covid-19, les organisateurs ont néanmoins établi une Sélection officielle parmi les quelque 2 067 longs-métrages qu’ils ont visionnés.</description>
</item>
<item numero="13" date="20200627">
<titre>A Paris, le cinéma Le Louxor se déconfine.</titre>
<description>Après cent jours de fermeture, le mythique cinéma a rouvert ses portes, avec de nouvelles mesures de sécurité. La photographe Sophie Garcia a assisté aux préparatifs et aux premières séances de projection.</description>
</item>
</file>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `==` and `eq`. You hash values are strings like

```
2020/06/01/19-36-00/0,2-3476,1-0,0.xml
other file.xml
```

`==` is the comparison operator for numbers, `eq` is for strings. You want to say

```
my @keys = grep {$items_file->{$_} eq $value} keys %$items_file;
```